# Trouble solving a system of partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of linear PDEs analytically and I dont get the answer. I am new to this tool, appreciate your help

```
z1 := xi1[x, y, z]
z2 := xi2[x, y, z]
z3 := xi3[x, y, z]

p1 := D[xi1[x, y, z], x]
q1 := D[xi1[x, y, z], y]
r1 := D[xi1[x, y, z], z]

p2 := D[xi2[x, y, z], x]
q2 := D[xi2[x, y, z], y]
r2 := D[xi2[x, y, z], z]

p3 := D[xi3[x, y, z], x]
q3 := D[xi3[x, y, z], y]
r3 := D[xi3[x, y, z], z]

eqn1 = c1*p1 + c2*p2 + c3*p3 == (ph1 - z1)*ga
eqn2 = c1*q1 + c2*q2 + c3*q3 == (ph2 - z2)*ga
eqn3 = c1*r1 + c2*r2 + c3*r3 == (ph3 - z3)*ga

DSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3},{xi1[x, y, z],xi2[x, y, z],xi3[x, y, z]},{x, y, z}]
```

Comment: "analytically and I dont get the answer" - and you have reason to believe that there's supposed to be a closed form?

Comment: No, actually. I would like to have an analytical solution thats all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

This is (I believe) better to post it here than in a comment.
Your system can be written in a much more clear way in Mathematica:

```
xi = Through[{xi1, xi2, xi3}[x, y, z]];
p = {ph1, ph2, ph3};
c = {c1, c2, c3};

eq = Thread[Tr /@ Transpose[c Grad[xi, {x, y, z}]] == (p - xi) ga];

DSolve[eq,xi,{x,y,z}]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I used your syntax but I get the following error:

Comment: Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of the one-dimensional list {c1 Grad[{xi1[x,y,z],xi2[x,y,z],xi3[x,y,z]},{x,y,z}],c2 Grad[{xi1[x,y,z],xi2[x,y,z],xi3[x,y,z]},{x,y,z}],c3 Grad[{xi1[x,y,z],xi2[x,y,z],xi3[x,y,z]},{x,y,z}]} cannot be transposed. >>

Comment: Hi, Now I got the syntax right, but I just get the same input equations as output. Please see the output below

Comment: Solve[{Tr[
    c1 Grad[{xi1[x, y, z], xi2[x, y, z], xi3[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]] ==
    ga (ph1 - xi1[x, y, z]), 
  Tr[c2 Grad[{xi1[x, y, z], xi2[x, y, z], xi3[x, y, z]}, {x, y, 
       z}]] == ga (ph2 - xi2[x, y, z]), 
  Tr[c3 Grad[{xi1[x, y, z], xi2[x, y, z], xi3[x, y, z]}, {x, y, 
       z}]] == ga (ph3 - xi3[x, y, z])}, {xi1[x, y, z], xi2[x, y, z], 
  xi3[x, y, z]}]

Comment: @Vinod Please see the comment by GuessWho under your question ...

Comment: thanks. you mean this system may not have analytical solution ?

Comment: @Vinod I don't know. Most systems don't. In any case, Mathematica can't find it.